# I can't @Autowire field in java @Configuration file

Tags: java, spring

My project is a mix of both Java configuration and XML configuration.

Please take a look at those files. I can't autowire `private DataSource dataSource;`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
```

and

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.packt.webstore" />
    <mvc:resources  location="/resources/"  mapping="/resource/**"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql:*****" />
        <property name="username" value="******" />
        <property name="password" value="******" />
    </bean>
    <bean id ="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10240000"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I get an error during application startup. These are the log details:

```
lip 27, 2016 4:59:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public javax.sql.DataSource com.packt.webstore.configuration.SecurityConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5066)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1863)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public javax.sql.DataSource com.packt.webstore.configuration.SecurityConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 60 more

lip 27, 2016 4:59:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

Comment: Please add more information where and when you get the error.#

Comment: I can't autowiere  private DataSource dataSource;

Comment: try arseniyandru advice, I think it could be the solution

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to include your xml config in Java config first.

```
@ImportResource("classpath:yourconfig.xml")
```

Comment: also the setDataSource seems redundant and the autowired field is never used

Comment: @ImportResource("classpath:webstore\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\spring\\webcontext\\DispatcherServlet-context.xml") I put this but it didn't help. I also changed the import definition to import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource. Well it says the such xml file dosent exist.

Comment: that file is not on the classpath and you shouldn't use \ in java (even if you're using windows)

Comment: Make sure files is in classpath,
try "classpath:spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml"
If still not found, then use absolute path (without classpath:) JUST TO TEST that bean is wired. Then you need to resolve your classpath issues.

Comment: The simplest way to add the file to the classpath is to put it in src/main/resources (if you're using maven or gradle with defaults, adjust if using something else); then you can simply use @ImportResource("classpath:Di‌​spatcherServlet-context.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write the definition of your Bean inside the Configuration class? You can have all your configuration inside there. You don't need an applicationContext.xml and a Configuration class.

Comment: I want to have both xml and java configuration. This is not an answer for my problem.

Comment: Looks like your Bean definition of the datasource at the xml is of a different type than the Configuration file.

The type of your datasource bean is `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` and the type of your @autowired datasource is `javax.sql.DataSource`, that's why Spring can't autowire it, because it can't find a Bean of the same type.

Comment: DriverManagerDataSource IS a javax.sql.DataSource, so I don't think that's the problem (unless there is more than one DataSource defined of course)

Answer (score 0):

No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean  - Looks like your DataSource is of a different type. Is there a mismatch between the type of dataSource in your Config and xml. `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` and `javax.sql.DataSource`.

Comment: I don't think just for the sake of the test I deletes this    private DataSource dataSource and replaced it with private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate. Just to test if it works(I definied this bean in my xml file) and this causes similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - Fix your import to be the same as your bean definition for you autowired object.

Is it possible that your import for the `DataSource` object is different from the bean definition in your spring xml?

In the exception, it clearly says:

> "No qualifying bean of type [**javax.sql.DataSource**] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency."

Where in your bean definition of your spring xml, you have:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
```

So, try fix your import statement to use the same one as your bean definition.

Comment: I did it but It didn't help.